# parse html in asp.net(c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, parsing

This is the current situation:
I have written a html document in asp.net.
The document has a table. I have given every cell a div with an ID. Thus i will have more options I can change later.
My problem:
I want to insert into every div of a cell a text or an image that will be inserted dynamically as the data that should be displayed in the divs comes from a database. To implement this I need to parse the HTML document. Thus I can allocate to every div a special text or image in asp.net via c#. I thought of using the id to address the specific div. As I haven't done anything concerning parsing I have no idea how to complete this task. I will be very helpful for every constructive answer and link.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Code exerts would be very helpful. :)

Comment: Why don't you insert the dynamic data into the HTML document while you're generating it?

Comment: Since you said, its generated dynamically, If you are considering doing this in the client(Browser), you can use jQuery. Its very easy, quick and handy. 
you can use $("#YOURCLIENTID") to get the element. jQuery will automatically parse everything for you.

you can use alert($("#YOURCLIENTID").html()) to see your cell's content. 
you can change your content using $("#YOURCLIENTID").html("my content here");

Comment: It seems you have a template and want to push the data in, would be good if you can have some placeholders in them like `[1]``[2]` which would be relevant and handy for replacement logic

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to parse html in c# code, you should look at [html agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

However the result you want to achieve can be easily achieved at client side using [jquery](http://jquery.com/). You can use the client side id of a div and some combination to create img tags.

Answer (score 2):

You should use XDocument and [XDocument.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse.aspx) to parse your html!

If you don't know Linq you have to learn some new things.

Comment: XML != HTML. If the HTML is not valid XML this can fail badly (`<br>` is valid HTML, not valid XML).

Comment: Yes. But if the document contains `<br>` and not `<br />`? The OP is not asking about XML or XHTML, but about HTML.

Comment: then the author changes the <br> to <br /> because you gave him the good advise! =)

Comment: You are forcing _your_ ideas on the OP. `<br>` and `<hr>` and `<input type=text />` are all _valid_ HTML. The OP may not be able to change it to be XML compatible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse, manipulate and save your HTML document.

> What is exactly the Html Agility Pack (HAP)?
>
> This is an agile HTML parser that builds a read/write DOM and supports plain XPATH or XSLT (you actually don't HAVE to understand XPATH nor XSLT to use it, don't worry...). It is a .NET code library that allows you to parse "out of the web" HTML files. The parser is very tolerant with "real world" malformed HTML. The object model is very similar to what proposes System.Xml, but for HTML documents (or streams).

Having said that, since you have `id` attributes on the different `div` elements, you can use a client side approach for this with Javascript (the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library makes many of the needed tasks very easy) and getting the needed data (text and image URIs) from the server using [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

Answer (score 0):

If you tolerate COM interoperability, you can also use MSHTML component. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb508516%28v=vs.85%29